# Image is not loading in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having a Django HTML page. I would like to display an image in an HTML file. I am returning like this.

in views.py

```
params = {
    'obj': obj,
    'data':data,
}
return render_to_string('records/record.html', params), obj
```

In html file

```
 <img src="{{data.image.path}}">
```

While logging what I am getting data.image.path like this

https://document.s3.amazonaws.com/others/path/20220809-150420-Screenshot-%2897%29.png?Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=6037f61de9173fcf2a2b556ef81e

In Django html page it replacing & to &amp.

Comment: That is coming because of your AWS configurations, you need to fix that first then only you will get your image without presigned url

Comment: Is there any way I can display & without showing &amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `{{data.image.path}}` to `{{data.image.url}}`